Specialization of points on the generic fiber in a prestable model of $\mathbb{P}^1$
Let $R$ be a complete DVR with uniformizer $\pi$, fraction field $K$ and residue field $k$. We assume $k$ is algebraically closed.
Let $X$ be a prestable model of $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ over $R$, so $X$ is proper and flat over $R$ with generic fiber $\mathbb{P}^1_K$. Assume for simplicity that the special fiber $X_k$ has just two components $X_0,X_1$ meeting at a node, and that there is a contraction map $c : X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1_R$ which contracts $X_1$ and is an isomorphism on $X_0$.
Let $x\in \mathbb{P}^1_K$ be a closed point which specializes to $\overline{x}\in\mathbb{P}^1_k$. I want to understand how the component that $\overline{x}$ lies on interacts with formal neighborhoods at $x$.
Suppose that $\overline{x}$ lies on $X_1 - X_0$. Then in $\mathbb{P}^1_R$, $x$ must specialize to $c(\overline{x})$. We can find a coordinate $t$ on $\mathbb{P}^1_R$ such that a formal neighborhood of the $R$-section $\{x,c(\overline{x})\}\subset\mathbb{P}^1_R$ looks like $f_t : \text{Spec }R[[t]]\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1_R$. The ring $R[[t]]$ is normal (in fact regular), so it is the intersection of DVR's containing it in its fraction field. Thus by properness of the contraction map, $f_t$ lifts to a map $f_t' : \text{Spec }R[[t]]\rightarrow X_R$.
However, this lift seems to have some contradictory properties: The point $(\pi)\in\text{Spec }R[[t]]$ maps via $f_t$ to the generic point of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, and hence under $f_t'$ it must map to the generic point $\eta$ of $X_0$. The point $(t)\in\text{Spec }R[[t]]$ must map, via $f_t'$, to $x$. Thus $f_t'((\pi,t))$ must lie in the closure of both $\eta$ and $x$, which is impossible since $\overline{\{\eta\}} = X_0$ is disjoint from $\overline{\{x\}} = \{x,\overline{x}\}$.
Where have I gone wrong?

Your argument that $f_t$ lifts to $f'_t$ is wrong.  If the contraction map were affine, it would be okay.  However the contraction map is not affine.

@JasonStarr Ahh great. To add some detail, the issue is that Spec $R[[t]]$ is an affine scheme colimit of the DVR's, but is not a colimit in the category of schemes, and in this case there is no single affine subscheme of $X$ that contains the images of all of the DVR's. (If there were, then the lifting would work). Is that right?

@JasonStarr If you'd like to post an answer I'd happily accept.

I am just posting my comment as one answer.  The poster's argument is correct in those cases where $c$ is an affine morphism (e.g., this can occur when one integral model is non-normal and $c$ is the normalization).  However, for the contraction of integral models specified in the post, the morphism $c$ is not affine: it has a proper curve as one fiber.
